# RSS images using SimpleXml not displaying.Works for .xml RSS feeds but not with .cms

Tags: php, laravel-5, simplexml

I get

main(): Node no longer exists

while trying to display images (media:content)from a Rss  url. I have been trying to solve it but was not successful . Can someone explain me Why this error is displaying and Help me solve it.the code works well if I Parsed RSS Feeds Urls with a .xml extension but not with a .cms Extension Urls.I Dont know why this is happening or whats wrong with my CODE.

My View

```
 foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {

                    $image=$data1[$key1]['image']->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->content->attributes()->url;

                    echo '<p>'.$image.'</p>';

                    echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><strong style="color:pink;">'.$data1[$key1]["title"].'</strong>';
                    echo '<p>'.$data1[$key1]["description"].'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$data1[$key1]["pubDate"].'</p>';
                    echo '</div>';

                }
```

My Controller

```
foreach($urls as $key => $url){

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        $result[$key]['title'] = $xml->channel->title;

        $data = [];

        for ($i=0; $i<5 ; $i++) { 
        # code...
            $items = [];
            if($xml->channel->item[$i] == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            $items['title'] = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $items['link'] = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
            $items['description'] = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
            $items['pubDate'] = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
            $items['image'] = $xml->channel->item[$i];

            $data[$i] = $items;

        }

        $result[$key]['data'] = $data;

        //$entries = array_merge($worldFeed,$entries);

    }





      return View::make('index')->with('result',$result);
```

Comment: So i found the problem...its because i added a url link [link]('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms',) but my code can only read URL with a .xml extension only e.g [link](http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Africa.xml) .I dont know exactly what the problem is or why Images cannot be parsed ...

Comment: The file extension has nothing to do with it - a URL can serve you whatever content it wants, under whatever URL. What you need to look at is the *content* given to you by those two URLs. Presumably, they have different XML structure, and your code assumes something about the structure that isn't true of the new data source. Without seeing some (*simplified*) examples of the XML, there's no way we can help you find out what that difference is.